# Regarding IBM TPM 7.2.1

Tags: tivoli, tpm

I was working for TPM 7.2.1 but I am not able to run tio.sh stop tpm or tio.sh start tpm. It is failing with below error.

ALR0401E: Connection Refused: Possible cause is the lightweight infrastructure is not running.

Anyone who has resolved this problem. I ran tioStatus.sh and it is running fine. I am using TPM 7.2.1 in Linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue is solved. We need to manually kill all the process using kill -9 PID and then restart the TPM again.